# What is the difference between 'same' and 'half' border mode in Convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between 'same' and 'half' border mode in Convolutional neural networks? I see it implemented differently in Theano and TF.

Answer (score 2):

- `full` means apply filter wherever it partly overlaps with the input, i.e. padding of dimension (`filter rows - 1`, `filter columns - 1`)
- `half` means that there is a padding of (`filter rows // 2 rows`, `filter columns // 2 columns`)
- `same` means there are some padding around input or feature map, making the output feature map's size same as the input's.
- `valid` means there is no padding around input or feature map, i.e. padding of dimension `(0,0)`.

---

Some sources if interested:

- [How does border_mode work? #1984](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207061656/https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1984)
- [border_mode='same' and/or custom zero padding for convolutions #2118](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207061649/https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2118)
- [Ops for convolutional neural nets](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207061643/http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html)
- [TensorFlow - Convolution](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207062021/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/convolution)
- [What is the difference between 'SAME' and 'VALID' padding in tf.nn.max_pool of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37674306/395857)

Comment: Why would one want `half` padding? If I understand it right, the output feature map is by exactly 1 smaller than the input feature map?

Answer (score 2):

The half padding is the same padding when the kernel size is odd and the stride is 1. In TensorFlow, we only have 'same' for the option for padding instead of 'half.' They are treated the same, and they work as the half.